# Vue Keep-Alive - Component App Header won't stay alive during route changes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router, keep-alive

I defined the main page of my vue app to look like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <keep-alive>
      <app-header></app-header>
    </keep-alive>
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>

<script>
import appHeader from '../components/Header';

export default {
  components: {
    appHeader
  }
/* etc... */
}
```

My app UI is basically starting from this component, with many different routes and sub-routes paths to show many pages, but in all pages (components) I want to show the app-header at the top of the page.

The problem is that I noticed recently, with every button clicked (that changes vue-router's route to another page), the app-header gets recreated (the created() lifecycle hook function is called)

I really don't understand why, since I added keep-alive, shouldn't it be rendered once?

Please help me figure this out, I am stuck, I literally researched the entire internet about it.

**Please note! I don't want the routes to stay alive, only the app header itself**

Here are links to view more of my code, which could might help you understand better:

1) [App.vue (Pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/txjaeYX9)

2) [Dashboard.vue (Pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/xhjyfeTs)

3) [Router files (Pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/YH30ixd9)

Please note that at main.js of Vue I import the router and put it first parameter in an object like "new Vue({router, store, vuetify, render: h => h(App)}).$mount('#app');". "App" is an import of App.vue posted, and vuetify is a plugin you all probably know already. Please let me know if you need anything else, I really appreciate your help!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<keep-alive>` is for saving the state of dynamic components i.e `<component :is="myComponent">`

Use `<router-link to="/myroute">` or `$router.push('/myroute')` to move between routes and the non dynamic components outside the `router-view` will maintain their state.

Here's a simple demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ellisdod/uzj8317m/

Comment: Thank you very much! :) My App.vue included a <router-view> and Dashboard.vue was the component with App Header and another <router-view>, so I did not realize Dashboard.vue was recreated everytime I change route, I just moved the AppHeader to App.vue the main component with a v-if to check if the $route.path starts with /dashboard/, only then it'd display